# scroll to important li on load div for example li class="importants"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, load

Its my first page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="comment"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#comment').load('comment.php');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

And its comment.php :

```
<ul id="comments" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <li>
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
    <li class="importants">
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>comment</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want `ul` scroll to `li.importants` after load.
`.importants` for show comment with scroll. (important comment)
Just this `ul` scrolls to bottom !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment').load('comment.php', function() {
        $("#comments").animate({scrollTop: $('.importants').offset().top - $("body").height() + 410});
    });
});
```

But it just work for your site !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment').load('comment.php', function() {
        $('#comments').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#comments').find('.importants').offset().top
        }, 400);    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 scrollTop: $('li .importants').offset().top
```